# Call EqualityComparer.Default with Cecil

Tags: c#, generics, mono.cecil

How can I generate the necessary IL code to call the `System.Collections.Generic.EqualityComparer<T>.get_Default` method with Mono Cecil?

I've tried similar variants of this but got diverse errors ranging from PEVerify not being able to resolve a token, over Cecil complaining that something is from another module and needs to be imported, to an ArgumentOutOfRangeException from Cecil itself.

The generic type argument comes from the `PropertyType` of a property I'm processing here.

```
PropertyDefinition propertyDef = ...;
var equalityComparer = typeDef.Module.ImportReference(typeof(System.Collections.Generic.EqualityComparer<>));
var equalityComparerInst = equalityComparer.MakeGenericInstanceType(propDef.PropertyType);
var getDefaultMethod = equalityComparerInst.Resolve().Methods.First(m => m.Name == "get_Default");
var getDefaultMethodRef = typeDef.Module.ImportReference(getDefaultMethod, getDefaultMethod);
il.Append(il.Create(OpCodes.Call, getDefaultMethodRef));
```

What code do I need for this?

Generic instances from other modules are always tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
 private static void CallEqualityComparerDefault()
 {
     string assemblyPath = $"{Environment.CurrentDirectory}\\ClassLibrary1.dll";
     var mainModule = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(assemblyPath).MainModule;

     var methodDef = mainModule.Types.First(
         type => type.Name == "TestClass").Methods.Single(m => m.Name == "TestMethod");

     var eq = mainModule.Import(typeof(EqualityComparer<>));
     var obj = mainModule.Import(typeof(object));
     var genericEq = new GenericInstanceType(eq);
     genericEq.GenericArguments.Add(obj);
     var importedGenericEq = mainModule.Import(genericEq);
     var defaultMethodDef = importedGenericEq.Resolve().Methods.Single(m => m.Name == "get_Default");
     var methodRef =  mainModule.Import(defaultMethodDef);
     methodRef.DeclaringType = importedGenericEq;

     var ilProcessor = methodDef.Body.GetILProcessor();
     ilProcessor.InsertBefore(
         ilProcessor.Body.Instructions.First(), 
         Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Callvirt, methodRef));
     methodDef.Body.OptimizeMacros();

     mainModule.Write(assemblyPath + ".new.dll");
 }
```

`ClassLibrary` is a dll that contains type called `TestClass` that contains method `TestMethod`.

Before I add the call to `EqualityComparer<>.Default` the method body looks like this:

```
IL_0000: nop
IL_0001: ret
```

And after:

```
IL_0000: callvirt class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.EqualityComparer`1<!0> class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.EqualityComparer`1<object>::get_Default()
IL_0005: nop
IL_0006: ret
```

Comment: Great, thank you! I almost missed the `methodRef.DeclaringType = importedGenericEq;` line but as it still didn't work for me I finally found that line, too.